# How to save settings in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

A couple of months ago I installed IntelliJ IDEA on my Windows 7 development computer. I also installed Maven.

Unfortunately I provided IntelliJ with the wrong path to Maven. Now it seems to be impossible to correct my mistake. I can't reconfigure IntelliJ IDEA with the correct settings to Maven and make my changes persistent, i. e. there is no **Save**-changes button?

[image]

Just pressing **OK** (or **Apply** followed by **OK**) doesn't seem to make IntelliJ remember the settings when it is restarted.

Will I always be doomed to keep my original, error-prone settings, or is there any way to deal with this obstacle? How can I save my new settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the hint is on your screenshot:

"M2_HOME is used by default".

Check your System paths:

1. Select Computer from the Start menu
2. Choose System Properties from the context menu
3. Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
4. Click on Environment Variables
5. Under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
6. Click on the Edit button, find the M2_HOME entry and change the path to the directory you want it to be.

Comment: Thank's for this! I believe you got me on the track:. My problems were two:
*I did exactly what you said but still no luck
*I unchecked the "override" box (according to my picture) and the problem was solved.
I mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Although this answer was accepted, it seems like this is not actually resolving the problem. Why have a settings window if the app is just going to override them from environment vars anyway?